# For SQL server with one User CAL, can one user be logged in concurrently from multiple devices?

Tags: sql-server, sql, sql-server-2012

So basically our client had no idea what they were doing when licensing SQL Server, and ended up only purchasing one User CAL. What I'm wondering is, can that same User CAL be used across multiple devices using the same login, so that only one user is ever logged in, or will that be impossible? Basically speaking, they have viewer PCs on a production line at a warehouse and want us to write a simple desktop application that will provide visibility to a table on their database which, previously, only their warehouse management system accessed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](http://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Comment: Off topic, because licensing question, but see the following quote: [With the User CAL, you purchase a CAL for every user who accesses the server to use services such as file storage or printing, regardless of the number of devices they use for that access](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/licensing/product-licensing/client-access-license.aspx).  Seems pretty clear to me.